# Subversion client for Windows

Tags: windows, version-control, subversion

I'm looking for a recommended Subversion client.

The requirements are:

- User-friendly to be used.
- More than 4 people to use it.
- If any possible that the application is free to use.
- In our case, we do not have a server at home so we would like the work to be applied in the internet. Something about subversion with internet.

We are four students who wants to use it. We use VS 2013 with SQL server 2012. We use Windows.

Comment: Assuming you're running on Wondows (if I deduce this correctly from between the lines?), would something like [Tortoise](http://tortoisesvn.net/) fit your needs? Plugs in to the Windows Shell, so you can basically use it via the standard Windows-Explorer. Free and OpenSource AFAIK. If you'd consider that a candidate, I'd set up a corresponing answer with more details.

Comment: Yes, we are using windows. What specification would you like me to inform you?

Comment: You tagged your question with [tag:sublime-text]. Does that mean the SVN client should be integrated with Sublime?

Comment: Steve already picked my idea to create his answer (the *Tortoise* part of it was I wanted to suggest, *after* making sure the environment matches – I don't like placing irrelevant answers), so I'm not going to repeat it, sorry. I however do not agree on the Mercurial part (I'd rather recommended Git, with the same arguments, and the corresponding graphical tools for the "user-friendly" part ;)

Comment: @Izzy The reason that I didn't mention git is that I find the command line interface rather daunting for anybody new to VCS compared to hg - (to be honest I find getting some people to use any VCS can be an issue).

Comment: That's quite subjective, and Git also ships with GUI stuff which is easy to use. Moreover, there are even free books available dig into it, e.g. [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/) localized (translated) to quite many languages (complete: 10, in parts: 14 more). But as that was not part of the question, we shouldn't go in depths on that ;)

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest either [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) as an SVN Client it is:

- free,
- easy to use, (integrates with file explorer),
- Windows
- Prerequisite for [VsTortoise](http://vstortoise.codeplex.com/) Visual Studio plugin.

**But** reading between the lines it sounds like you have no access to the internet some of the time and do not have a server.  This being the case you would be better off looking to use [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)

- Free
- Easy to use
- Cross Platform
- NO SERVER NEEDED
- Can even act as its own server!
- There is also a [tortoisehg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/) offering file explorer integration for mercurial
- Visual Studio hg plugin [available](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/).

Comment: SVN can be used "server-less", when using the `file:///` protocol, so it takes a local folder as the server, and commits/updates from there. Not so good for a shared work, however. Otherwise, I like the mercurial suggestion, too.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the recommendation for TortoiseSVN, I would like to add [VsTortoise](http://vstortoise.codeplex.com/). It's a plugin for Visual Studio that adds some commands that launch the TortoiseSVN right from the project, making it somewhat easier to use SVN from within VS. Basically, it gives a series of shortcuts, if you prefer to remain in one environment, but it's a great time saver. It still requires TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Forgot to mention that there is also an hg plugin for VS.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the Visual Studio plugin [ANKHSVN](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/). It is mature and stable and has one great advantage: it adds files to Subversion automatically that you add to your solution.